# redirection usage in bash shell

Tags: bash, shell

Belows are the code what I want to understand:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat > pl.gp <<EOF
...
CONTENTS
...
EOF
```

The resultant of this `shell` script gives a `pl.gp` file which contains every texts before `EOF` meets. Does anyone help me understand this powerful redirection usage of shell?

Comment: Reading [the Bash manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) might help.

Comment: In `cat > pl.gp << EOF`, what is the execution order?

Comment: You only execute *one* command, `cat`, therefore there is no ordering.

Comment: It is a "here document". You have figured it out already, but look up "here documents".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a [heredoc](http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-here.html).

Everything from the `<<EOF` up to the following `EOF` token is fed into the `cat` process on its stdin. `cat` (by its nature) will then dump it out into the nominated file via stdout redirection (the `>` operator)